# How to create multiple fixtures in a body by using PhysicsEditor

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

I want to create a land in my game. The land is composed of some pictures named "ground1.png" , "ground2.png" and so on. I use the PhysicsEditor to draw the shape of b2Fixture with these pictures.
The Question is how to set the position of these shapes. The land just like "ground2.png" after "ground1.png" and "ground3.png" after "ground2.png".
However, addFixturesToBody() is not appropriate.

```
GB2ShapeCache::sharedGB2ShapeCache()->addFixturesToBody(land, "ground1");
GB2ShapeCache::sharedGB2ShapeCache()->addFixturesToBody(land, "ground2");
```

Unfortunately, the shape named "ground2" will cover the shape named "ground2".
I wand the "ground2" after the "ground1".
Can I achieve this idea by using PhysicsEditor or coding?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use separate bodies for each ground segment. PE isn't the right tool to do entire world collision shapes (at least not yet).

Though using multiple large shapes on a single body can be quite inefficient for Box2D's contact detection algorithm. And besides performance, there can be issues when you move a body over two connected points (body getting stuck even on flat terrain). Read the [section on chain shapes in the Box2D manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082970).

Really the best way to create world collision shapes is to use a series of connected b2ChainShape shapes. You can't create those with PhysicsEditor unfortunately. PE internally uses b2PolygonShape and b2CircleShape.

However tracing the world's outline is no trivial task, search for contour tracing algorithm. So maybe the best compromise is to create the polygon shapes with PE and then derive chain shapes from those, properly spaced. You may need to modify the GBShapeCache code for that, if only to expose its shapes list.